# Texshop: Jump back to the editor after compiling

Tags: texshop, keyboard, shortcut

I was wondering if there is a shortcut to jump back to the editor after compiling. I am using Texshop and after I use Cmd+T to compile the pdf file, the cursor will focus on the pdf file instead of the editor. I have to click the mouse to go back to the editor. Is there a shortcut so I could do that without leaving my keyboard?

Comment: Doesn't CMD+' do so? I think there are shortcuts given if you look into the menu.

Comment: @TeXnician Command-' simply moves through the layers of windows open (this is a MacOS command) so it's not guaranteed to get you to the source of your PDF. However, Command-1 (a TeXShop key binding) will move you to the source of the PDF in focus (and vice versa).

Comment: Yes, Cmd-1 jumps back and forth between the Source and Preview window. To set it permanently see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Under the Typesetting tab of TeXShop->Preferences choose Continue Editing in the After Typesetting section.